# ISCSI sessions appear from nowhere

Tags: windows, hyper-v, iscsi

I am using Win2008 32bit Ent. running in Hyper-V with 2 LUNs over ISCSI connection (this is a MS cluster with one LUN being quorum and second as a storage). In ISCSI -> target -> details I see multiple sessions from same target (currently 7), however I am not sure where they are coming from as I have only one virtual NIC on this server. Sure enough 2 LUNs appear 7 times each in device manager or in disk manager. On the cluster partner however, I do not see that problem. There is only one session per target. Installing MPIO makes only difference - I am getting 8 sessions instead of 7 once I reboot.

Does any one know what can cause this behavior?

Comment: How is your iscsi target configured? IIRC you should configure a SCSI ID to avoid duplicates with Hyper-V.

Answer (score 1):

That's normal behavior. It creates separate sessions for every possible combination of network routes. So if any routes fail, the others pick up the slack.

See these links for more info: [Understanding MPIO](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee619734(WS.10).aspx) and [Configuring MPIO](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee619752(WS.10).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Sessions and connections

you will see a New LUN for each Session in windows 7 sessions 7 luns.

It sounds like you want to make Multiple Connections not sessions